# Trying to access this JSON attribute, but my method is not working (screenshot of JSON object provided)

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

For the sake of simplicity, and to make our lives easier, I just took a screen shot of the JSON object, here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxwe.png

Right now, I am trying to access 1's __text value. I use this code, which I am able to access other attribute:value pairs, like the title under 0.

```
entireJSON.TEI.text.body.div.forEach(function(entry) {
   entry.p.forEach(function(dp) {
      var dateCurr = dp.title; // this works fine
   }
}
```

But where it goes wrong is when I try the following code (I've tried other variations too). I've tried many different kinds of syntax, and I just can't get it. How do I access the attribute:value (__text:text's value) under 1?

```
entireJSON.TEI.text.body.div.forEach(function(entry) {
   entry.p.forEach(function(dp) {
      var dateCurr = dp.title; // this works fine

       dp.persName.forEach(function(test) { // DOESN'T WORK
         console.log(test.__text); //DOESNT'T WORK
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using a conditional since the first index `p[0]` doesn't have a property for `persName` in the screenshot and would throw an error like `Cannot reach property forEach of undefined`

```
entireJSON.TEI.text.body.div.forEach(function(entry) {
   entry.p.forEach(function(dp) {
      var dateCurr = dp.title; // this works fine

       // if it's an array
       if (Object.prototype.toString.call(dp.persName) === '[object Array]') {
           dp.persName.forEach(function(test) { // DOESN'T WORK
             console.log(test.__text); //DOESNT'T WORK
           });
       } else {
           // everything else
           console.log(dp.persName);
       }
   });
});
```

You can still use `Array.isArray` if you just want to support modern browsers.

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb. I swear I tried that, but I guess I didn't. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, with the inner if statement you posted, I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". It gets through most of the names, but stops at a point.

Comment: @AnthonyJ if it works for the first few names then it's possible that `persName` further in the array is not an array.  Could you show me more of the data?   Or if you don't mind skipping anything that's not an Array, you could change the conditional to `Array.isArray(dp.persName)`

Comment: Wow... you are right on the dot. I didn't notice that persName is no longer an array until I tried this code. The problem is, I need everything from persName whether it is an array or not. I'm running into this issue because I am using a JS library called, x2js, which converts XML to JSON. So all the JSON I am going through has been converted to XML. I will try your conditional for the persNames that are arrays, and have an else for the non-array and see if I can deal with them all that way.

Comment: @AnthonyJ I've updated the code to `console.log` anything else if it's not an array.  Should work until you hit an object then you'd have to figure something out since I don't know the structure of the data.

Comment: The structure looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/yr16437.png You'll see under persName, under the 2 and 9, the structure is different. Is there a quick way to access those values?

Comment: @AnthonyJ you can access `test` as is if the item in the array is just a string.  For testing purposes, try this statement `console.log(test.__text || test)`.